# What does "I got sick" mean?

Tags: past-tense, adjectives

1. I was sick
2. I got sick

In the first sentence "sick" is used as an adjective, and the sentence is referring a state. But in "I got sick" the sentence is saying you were sick because of something/it shows transition to sick.

Did I understand correctly?

Comment: What's the context? It can mean different things.

Comment: As in yesterday.

Comment: That's still not enough context. For example, the meaning of "I can't believe that I got sick with two viruses in a row" is different from "Don't go in there — I got sick on the carpet."

Comment: As "got" describes action rather than state. eg "I got tired yesterday" means "I was tired yesterday" here "tired" is not used as an adjective but a verb. Similarly i reckon in "I got sick", "sick" is used as a verb instead of "an adjective"

Comment: Your question has several different answers depending on what you mean. Please edit your question to provide a clear and unambiguous context, including what you mean by "sick". Also, "sick" is not a verb

Comment: @gotube. I edited my question now kindly have a look pls.

Comment: I definitely do not understand what you are asking or why you keep mentioning parts of speech. But let me just observe that we sometimes use the word 'got' in passive constructions (I got invited; I got overlooked; I got photographed) where 'got' is interchangeable with 'was' and the following word is a verb. Although 'got' is also interchangeable with 'was' in these constructions (I got sick; I got cold) they are not grammatically parallel to the first group. Only the first group translate to active constructions (Someone invited me; someone overlooked me; someone photographed me).

Comment: @Chaim.What would "I got used to travelling" mean? Whether it means ( i was used to travelling/adjective/state or "I was used to travelling/as in acquiring the action"?

Comment: Still not clear. Are you asking about "sick" or about the difference between *[ "get" + adjective ]* and *[ "be" + adjective ]* ?

Comment: Are you intending to use British or American English? In BrE, _I was sick_ commonly means _I vomited_, though in a business context it could mean _I was unwell (I was on sick leave)_. In AmE, _I got sick_ would mean _I became ill_ (open to correction).

Comment: @gotube.@Kate Bunting. I want to ask what would be difference between simple " I was sick" and "I got sick" where 'got' is also interchangeable with 'was'.  Secondly in "I got used to travelling "used to travelling is an adjective" "got+adjective" but "used to travelling" could also be "verb"and then the construction would be "I got+ used to travelling/verb

Comment: @Chaim. I know "I get sick/cold) could Although 'got' is also interchangeable with 'was' in these constructions (I got sick; I got cold)  i become sick/cold(adjectives) but As you said earlier although 'got' is also interchangeable with 'was' in these constructions (I got sick; I got cold). And as "sick/cold" were adjectives there.Could you pls tell me if "get" is also interchangeable with "is/am/are in these construction (He gets sick, i get cold, They are confused)(sick,cold,confused are adjective here)

Comment: To me, the use of "get" in the present tense, "I get cold," idiomatically means that I typically get cold, while "I am cold" does not mean that I am often cold, but just that I am cold right now.  But I supposed that in general, someone "gets" something, whether an adjective or a passive verb, will change to someone "is" something, with only a subtle or idiomatic change in meaning, if any.

Comment: I understand "I got used to it" to mean "I became used to it, I became familiar or comfortable with it." But I suppose that close examination of these common idioms might reveal that we all think of them slightly differently, without much implication for the way we use them.

Comment: @chaim if I say "I got in touch with him" could I interpret "got" as in "became" as in "I became in touch with him".could I also interpret "got" as in "i have been or "was" in touch with him?

Comment: I suppose that if my brother and I fall out of touch, and then out of the blue he calls me, it would be natural to say that he got in touch with me but strange to say that I got in touch with him. While each of us did come to be in touch with the other, he played the active role so should be described as getting in touch with me, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Get* **can** be used to form the passive of verbs, and *tire* is a verb, so in theory *got tired* could be a passive of *tire*. But *tired* is hardly ever used that way : it is almost always an adjective, and so it is here. This is not "passive" *get*, it is "inchoative" or "transitional" *get*. "I got tired" means "I became tired".

With *sick*, *sick* is not a verb, it is an adjective, so this cannot be passive *get*. It is again "inchoative" *get* - *I got sick* is an informal way of saying *I became sick*. As far as I can tell, they are identical in meaning.

If instead of *sick* you name a particular disease, as in *I got a cold* (past tense of *I'm getting a cold*), this is another *get* - literally, to obtain, or acquire something. An alternative in this sense would be *I caught a cold*. (You can also say *I caught cold* without an article, but not *I got cold* in that sense, because the adjective *cold* would be undersood rather than the noun *a cold*, and we would be back to the inchoative meaning: *I became cold*, or *I started to feel cold*.

Comment: Do you not think "I have got a cold"/posession (I have a cold) is much better instead of " I got a cold"

Comment: I think "I got sick" could also be passive, If I interpret "I got sick" as "I was sick" because of something/transition to sick.

Comment: @BilalZafarI've edited my answer to clarify that _I got a cold_ was intended to be the simple past of _I'm getting a cold_. That uses the verb _got_, past of _get_, and is a different construction to _I have (got) a cold_ which uses the presnt tense of the verb _have_ or the compound verb _have got_.

Comment: @BilalZafar,  _I got sick_ cannot possibly be passive. "Passive" is the name of a construction which transforms a clause with a transitive verb, to raise the direct object to become the subject, eg _I ate the cake_ -> _The cake was/got eaten by me_.  While _get_ can be transitive, and form a passive, eg _The cake was got out of the box_ (AmE _gotten_), in _I got sick_, it is not transitive, as _sick_ is an adjectival complement, not a direct object. We can't say _*Sick was got(ten) by me_ which would be the putative pasive form.

Answer (score 1):

Got is past tense for get. I got sick just means you went through the process of contracting an illness that made you sick.