# "I get sick" Is "is" interchangeable with "'I am" as in "I am sick"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, american-english, british-english, adjective-phrases

I know 'I got sick/ cold" mean "I became sick/cold" and "sick/cold" are used as adjectives but
Here "Chime" said [What does "I got sick" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322139/what-does-i-got-sick-mean/322142?noredirect=1#comment606220_322142)

'got' is also interchangeable with 'was' in these constructions (I got sick; I got cold)

And i do know that If i say "I get sick/cold" it means "I become sick/cold" and "sick/cold" are used as adjectives.

Could you pls tell me if "get" is also interchangeable with "is/am/are in these construction (He is sick, I am cold, They are confused)(sick,cold,confused are adjective here

Comment: @Chaim's comment rather confuses the issue. Stick with your knowledge that _I got cold_ means _I became cold_.

Comment: In this context, "get" means "become", which is not the same as "is". If you are sick, then it's obvious that you got sick, so one expression can be used to mean the other one, but "interchangeable" is too big a word. What exactly are you asking? Just like your other question, it's still not clear what you want

Comment: @gotube thanks for getting back 
actually  according to chime, got' is also interchangeable with 'was' in these constructions (I got sick; I got cold)  So i wanted to ask if "get" is also interchangeable with "is/am/are in these construction (He is sick, I am cold, They are confused)(sick,cold,confused are adjective here) but Kate Bunting clearfied my query.

Comment: @kate bunting If i  say "I got in touch with him" could I interpret "got" as in "became" as in "I became in touch with him".could I also interpret "got" as in "i have been or "was" in touch with him?

Comment: @gotube if I say "I got in touch with him" could I interpret "got" as in "became" as in "I became in touch with him".could I also interpret "got" as in "i have been or "was" in touch with him?

Comment: You could interpret 'I got in touch with him' as 'I put myself in the situation of being in contact with him'. In my (British) English it doesn't mean 'I was (already) in touch with him'.

Comment: @KateBunting  what i understood is If i say "I  got in touch with him" that could be equaivalent to "I became in touch with him" Am i right?

Comment: _Getting in touch_ is a deliberate action. You can't 'become' in touch with someone - one or other of you has to make the first move (or a third person might _put you in touch_ with one another.

Answer (score 1):

"I am sick" and other variations are almost exclusively American English. British people normally say "I am *ill*" (or other colloquial alternatives such as *poorly*). In British English, "sick" normally refers to an instance of vomiting, depending on how it is used (eg "I have been sick", or "I was sick").

When you say "cold", are you referring to the common cold, an illness? As this is a noun it is normally used with an article, eg "I have **a** cold". But if you mean that you became cold due to a drop in temperature, for example, then you can say "I am cold", "I became cold" etc.

Aside from these points, the variations you suggest would be correct.

Comment: @Astralbee.Kindly correct me If I am wrong, what i interpreted is that "get" is also interchangeable with "is/am/are in these construction (He is sick, I am cold, They are confused)(where sick,cold,confused are used as adjective here)

Comment: @BilalZafar "Am" is present tense. "I am sick" means you're sick **now**. "I got sick" is past-tense, meaning you became sick in the past. "I get sick" would mean that you have a tendency to become sick.